# DES3 decryption in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, encoding, openssl

My RoR server receives a string, that was encrypted in C++ application using des3 with base64 encoding

The cipher object is created so:

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher::new("des3")
cipher.key = key_str
cipher.iv =  iv_str
```

key_str and iv_str: are string representations of key and initialization vector for encryption algorithm. They are the same for RoR and C++ application.

The code on the RoR side is following:

```
result = ""
result << cipher.update( Base64.decode64(message) )
result << cipher.final
```

After executing the last line of code, i get an exception

```
OpenSSL::CipherError (bad decrypt)
```

What is wrong here ? Any ideas ?

Comment: last line? what is the variable chiper? an AR object? also what does the final method?

Comment: As this tutorial says, http://olabini.com/blog/2008/08/ruby-security-quick-guide/
"Finally you need to call final to get the last generated cipher text"
I suppose, that this method is simmilar to flush method for streams.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation for [OpenSSL::Cipher](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html) states:

> Make sure to call `.encrypt` or `.decrypt` before using any of the following
>   methods:
>
> - [`key=`, `iv=`, `random_key`, `random_iv`, `pkcs5_keyivgen`]

In your specific case, omitting the call to `cipher.decrypt` causes a `bad decrypt` error, as you've seen.

The following example corrects that problem and exhibits the expected behavior:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'Base64'

# For testing purposes only!
message = 'MyTestString'
key = 'PasswordPasswordPassword'
iv = '12345678'

# Encrypt plaintext using Triple DES
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("des3")
cipher.encrypt # Call this before setting key or iv
cipher.key = key
cipher.iv = iv
ciphertext = cipher.update(message)
ciphertext << cipher.final

puts "Encrypted \"#{message}\" with \"#{key}\" to:\n\"#{ciphertext}\"\n"

# Base64-encode the ciphertext
encodedCipherText = Base64.encode64(ciphertext)

# Base64-decode the ciphertext and decrypt it
cipher.decrypt
plaintext = cipher.update(Base64.decode64(encodedCipherText))
plaintext << cipher.final

# Print decrypted plaintext; should match original message
puts "Decrypted \"#{ciphertext}\" with \"#{key}\" to:\n\"#{plaintext}\"\n\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gem install encryptor
```

It wraps the standard Ruby OpenSSL library and allows you to use any of its algorithms.

```
require 'encryptor'
Base64.decode64(message).decrypt(:algorithm => 'des', :key => key, :iv => iv)
```